# What is $p(A|B')$?

Tags: probability

Assume $p(A)=1/4$ and $p(B)=1/3$ and $p(A \cup B)=5/12$.

> What is $p(A|B')$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! It is helpful if you provide some context, what you have tried and where you are having difficulty. Here is a mathjax tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** You have
$$
P(A|B')=\frac{P(A\cap B')}{P(B')}
$$ and you have
$$
P(A\cap B')=P(A)-P(A \cap B)
$$
$$
P(A \cap B) =P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)
$$
$$P(B')=1-P(B)$$ 
Hoping you can take it from here.

Comment: wow it seems so obvious now. i feel so silly. thank you. i really like maths but moments like these you know...